# Is there any way to use authentication with proxy in Awesomium?

Tags: awesomium

I can't seem to find a way to use proxies with username and password (http/socks4). Any input would be great :)

I 'm using the .net wrapper, but I guess that does not make any difference.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 3):

You need to handle the WebControl `LoginRequest` Event, that is if you
   want to specify the user name an password in code

```
private void webcontrol_LoginRequest (object sender, LoginRequestEventArgs e)
                {
                    e.Username = "username";
                    e.Password = "password";
                    e.Handled = EventHandling.Modal;
                    e.Cancel = false;
                }
```

Test:

```
 WebPreferences prefs = new WebPreferences() { ProxyConfig = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port" };
    session = WebCore.CreateWebSession(prefs);
    webcontrol = new WebControl() { WebSession = session };
    webcontrol.LoginRequest += new LoginRequestEventHandler(webcontrol_LoginRequest);
```

- if you don't want to handle the event then you'll get a dialoge that
  you can enter the credintials in.