# Awesomium C# WebControl, change proxy settings

Tags: c#, proxy, awesomium

How can i change the proxy settings in Awesomium (c#)?
i've this simple code for now

```
Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl browser =
    new Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl();

browser = new Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl();
browser.Paint += browser_Paint;
browser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 1);
browser.Name = "webControl";
browser.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1024, 768);
browser.Source = new System.Uri("http://checkip.dyndns.com/", System.UriKind.Absolute);
browser.TabIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  WebPreferences prefs = new WebPreferences(){ ProxyConfig = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port" }
  session = WebCore.CreateWebSession(prefs);
  browser.WebSession = session; 
  browser.Source = new System.Uri("http://checkip.dyndns.com/", System.UriKind.Absolute);
```

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022304/is-there-any-way-to-use-authentication-with-proxy-in-awesomium/18789078#18789078) answer for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can set the proxy configuration on the WebCore that governs all of your webcontrols. Have a look at the [WebCoreConfig.ProxyServer Property](http://awesomium.com/docs/1_6_3/sharp_api/html/4e0b6e20-aa5f-de8c-aca3-c32c9e53dccd.htm).

You need to create a WebCoreConfig object and then use it during WebCore construction.

Take a look at the [WebCore API](http://awesomium.com/docs/1_6_3/sharp_api/html/a0a09478-96b5-a264-7976-b8f5e456ead8.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a WebSessionProvider control from the Toolbox to your form. Then set your Webcontrol's WebSessionProvider property to the one you just added.

Then, go (always in designer view) to the newly added WebSessionProvider's properties and expand the Preferences one: you will then find a ProxyConfig value to be filled with whatever proxy configuration you want to use.